# Multiple SELECT With Multiple WHERE

Tags: mysql

I am stumped and need your help.

I am trying to select three columns from my table where one of them is a VARCHAR and the other two are either "Y" or "N".

```
SELECT  CurrencyPair, Count(Accepted) As Accepted, Count(Successful) As Successful
    FROM  Trades
    WHERE  Accepted = "Y"
    GROUP BY  CurrencyPair
    ORDER BY  Successful/Accepted DESC, Successful DESC
    LIMIT  5
```

This returns a table just as I like in regards to format, but the data seems to only show where the three columns coincide. For example id three were accepted and two were successful I would expect the count for accepted to be 3 and the count for successful to be 2. My table always returns the same number of accepts and successes despite knowing the data in the table having more accepted than successes.

Furthermore, please have a look at the division operator to make sure it is correct syntax. It's purpose is to place higher success ratios at top.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post create table statement for your table for others to help you fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use case inside count:

```
Count(Case WHEN Successful = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Regarding division operator, looks ok, if you want to order by count.